# Returning data from XML into a UI

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have some code which loops through an XML file, and gets each instance of `<savedPositions>`. I am trying to add the data from each into a array so that I can then return it and use the strings in my UI - I'm not sure how to read the data back into my application, by displaying each instance of `<savedPositions>` on each button click. This means I only get one instance of `<savedPositions>` displayed into my text boxes.

How would I make it so that on each button click the text boxes are updated with the next `<savedPositions>` information? - Thanks

My XML:

```
<savedPositions>
  <savedPosition>
    <nBehaviour>nBehaviour1</nBehaviour>
    <aBehaviour>aBehaviour1</aBehaviour>
    <findings>findings1</findings>
    <forces>forces1</forces>
    <gap>gap1</gap>
    <position1>0.6488889</position1>
    <position2>-1000.0</position2>
  </savedPosition>
  <savedPosition>
    <nBehaviour>nBehaviour2</nBehaviour>
    <aBehaviour>aBehaviour2</aBehaviour>
    <findings>findings2</findings>
    <forces>aBehaviour2</forces>
    <gap>gap2</gap>
    <position1>-1000.0</position1>
    <position2>-1000.0</position2>
  </savedPosition>
</savedPositions>
```

Reading XML Code:

```
public class XmlToObject {

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> main() {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> obj1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> obj = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document d = db.parse("/home/nicolas/savedPos.xml");
            XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            NodeList nl = (NodeList) xp.compile("//savedPosition").evaluate(d, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println("number of saved positions " + nl.getLength());

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                String a = (xp.compile("./nBehaviour").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String b = (xp.compile("./aBehaviour").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String c = (xp.compile("./gap").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String d1 = (xp.compile("./forces").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String e = (xp.compile("./findings").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String f = (xp.compile("./position1").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String g = (xp.compile("./position2").evaluate(nl.item(i)));

                ArrayList<String> savedPosition = new ArrayList<String>();
                savedPosition.add(a);
                savedPosition.add(b);
                savedPosition.add(c);
                savedPosition.add(d1);
                savedPosition.add(e);
                savedPosition.add(f);
                savedPosition.add(g);

                obj.add(savedPosition);

            }

            return obj;

        } catch (Exception l) {
            System.out.println(l.getMessage());
        }

        return obj1;
    }
}
```

Calling XML on button click:

```
load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> obj = XmlToObject.main();

        for(ArrayList<String> r: obj){
            for(int i = 0; i < r.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(r.get(i) + "");
            }
            textArea.setText(r.get(0));
            textArea1.setText(r.get(1));
            textArea2.setText(r.get(2));
            textArea3.setText(r.get(3));
            textArea4.setText(r.get(4));
            mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().setPosition(Float.parseFloat(r.get(5)));
            mediaPlayerComponent2.getMediaPlayer().setPosition(Float.parseFloat(r.get(6)));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse your XML file only once, and declare an integer to keep track of the position which is currently displayed

```
    List<List<String>> obj = XmlToObject.main();
    int displayedPositionIndex = 0;
```

Then on your ActionListener, increase your counter and display the next position

```
load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        displayedPositionIndex++;
        if(displayedPositionIndex >= obj.size()) {
            displayedPositionIndex = 0; // to loop back to first after last position
        }
        setPosition(displayedPositionIndex);
    }
});
```

I use this utility method to make things clearer

```
private void setPosition(int index) {
    List<String> positionData = obj.get(index);
    textArea.setText(positionData.get(0));
    textArea1.setText(positionData.get(1));
    textArea2.setText(positionData.get(2));
    textArea3.setText(positionData.get(3));
    textArea4.setText(positionData.get(4));
    mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().setPosition(Float.parseFloat(positionData.get(5)));
    mediaPlayerComponent2.getMediaPlayer().setPosition(Float.parseFloat(positionData.get(6)));
}
```

**Note**

In your XmlToObject, it is better practice to use `List<List<String>>` than `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` (always use the interface if you can):

```
class XmlToObject {

    public static List<List<String>> main() {
        List<List<String>> positions = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document d = db.parse("/path/to/savedPos.xml");
            XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            NodeList nl = (NodeList) xp.compile("//savedPosition").evaluate(d, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println("number of saved positions " + nl.getLength());

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                String a = (xp.compile("./nBehaviour").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String b = (xp.compile("./aBehaviour").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String c = (xp.compile("./gap").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String d1 = (xp.compile("./forces").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String e = (xp.compile("./findings").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String f = (xp.compile("./position1").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                String g = (xp.compile("./position2").evaluate(nl.item(i)));

                List<String> savedPosition = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d1, e, f, g);
                positions.add(savedPosition);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return positions;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that works perfect - I've been trying to figure this out for an age! Have a great day!

Comment: @Benteye I've just noticed if the XML is file is created in the session then the XmlToObject class returns nothing - even though my XML file has data in it. Do you know this happens?

Comment: @McRoland in XmlToObject, add a check, using `File.exists()` before doing `Document d = db.parse("/path/to/savedPos.xml");` If the file exists and has data, then it should work. You probably are calling it at a point where the file is not there yet.

Comment: @Benteye Thanks that was exactly the problem - I was calling it at the wrong point XmlToObject.main();